# Why do I ger "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, http-error

I have a `Users` class like below:

```
class Users {
  
  static async findAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
      .then((rows) => {
        res.status(200).json(rows[0]);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({error: err});
        throw err;
        });
    next();

  }
}
```

And a `usersRouter` like following:

```
router.route("/api/users")
  .get(Users.findAll);
```

When I send a get request to `localhost:3000/api/users` I get the users list back but alongside with an Error as following:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

PS: The `pool` is a `mysql2/promise` pool.

Comment: Why are you calling `next()`?

Comment: @Phil: To prevent server from crashing if it caught an error.

Comment: But you're already handling the error and sending a response. You shouldn't be re-throwing `err` either

Comment: @Phil: It seems it works by removing the `next()` but I am still wondering to know when/where should I use `next()` if we can handle the error by using `catch()`?

Comment: Remove the call to `next()`.  If you're going to send a response to this request, then you do NOT want to continue routing to other handlers by calling `next()`.

Comment: You use `next()` in order to pass the request on to the next matching handler. If you pass an argument to it, eg `next(err)`, it will go on to the global error handler. If you're handling all logic / error paths, there's no need to call it.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes I did it and it worked, but I am wondering to know what is the `next()` use case?

Comment: `next()` is used when you have NOT sent a response and you want to continue routing, typically in middleware.

Comment: Outside middleware, it's used for [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)